# How to use find while ignoring formatting

Tags: excel, search, formatting, find, vba

I have the below code setup but I'm running to to errors when I have a value in a cell a 2 for example but in the search field it shows as 2.0 causing an error int he search loop. How can I avoid that?

Another example is in the value range I have a value that is 21.1 and a 21.11 they are both formatting as 21.1 but the code is only working on 21.1 and when it searches for 21.11 I get an error

```
For Each updRng1 In updRange1
'updates subtask info
    WorkRng2.Parent.Activate
    WorkRng2.Find(what:=updRng1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Select
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, subTskRng.Column).Copy
    WorkRng1.Parent.Activate
    updRange1.Find(what:=updRng1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues).Select
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Me.txtSubTask.Value).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Do you have a value 21.11 for it to find? It doesn't matter how you format it, the value is still `21.11`. Perhaps you should round your numbers before searching? `what:=round(updRng1.value, 1)`

Comment: @JNevill yes, the value exists. I actually added code to format both ranges as txt and it seems to work `updRange1.NumberFormat = "@"`

Comment: Why don't you attend to your other question?

Comment: Problem solved then.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for pointing that out, I didn't realize before. I will mark answers

Comment: @ScottCraner cool, all done. even gave me more reputation points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by formating the ranges as text using: `updRange1.NumberFormat = "@"`